# jsTree seems not working with jQuery layout

Tags: jstree, jquery-layout

My project need use a tree view to be in jQuery layout pane.
I chose jsTree as treeview control, but it seems not working with jQuery layout?
I created a quick sample to reproduce and demo the issue here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEgdl

The treeview is not loaded properly.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I figured it out. I missed the jstree css. jsTree and jQuery layout can work together.